# How to recursive traversal directory using ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

My real task is to recursive traversal a remote directory using paramiko with multi-threading.  For the sake of simplicity, I just use local filesystem to demonstrate it:

```
from pathlib import Path
from typing import List
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, Executor

def listdir(root: Path, executor: Executor) -> List[Path]:
    if root.is_dir():
        xss = executor.map(lambda d: listdir(d, executor), root.glob('*'))
        return sum(xss, [])
    return [root]

with ThreadPoolExecutor(4) as e:
    listdir(Path('.'), e)
```

However, the above code running without end.

What's wrong with my code? And how to fix it (better to use `Executor` rather than the raw `Thread`)?

**EDIT:** I have confirmed @Sraw 's answer by the following code:

```
In [4]: def listdir(root: Path, executor: Executor) -> List[Path]:
   ...:     print(f'Enter {root}', flush=True)
   ...:     if root.is_dir():
   ...:         xss = executor.map(lambda d: listdir(d, executor), root.glob('*'))
   ...:         return sum(xss, [])
   ...:     return [root]
   ...:

In [5]: with ThreadPoolExecutor(4) as e:
   ...:     listdir(Path('.'), e)
   ...:
Enter .
Enter NonRestrictedShares
Enter corporateActionData
Enter RiskModelAnnualEPS
Enter juyuan
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a dead lock inside your code.

As you are using `ThreadPoolExecutor(4)`, there are only four work threads in this executor, so you cannot run more than four tasks at the same time.

Image the following simplest structure:

```
test
----script.py
----test1
--------test2
------------test3
----------------test4
--------------------test5
```

If `python script.py`, the first work thread handles `test1`, the second one handles `test1/test2`, the third one handles `test1/test2/test3`, the fourth one handles `test1/test2/test3/test4`. And now the work threads are exhausted. But there is another task `test1/test2/test3/test4/test5` inserted into work queue.

So it will hang forever.

Comment: Thanks, is there any simple way to fix my code? I'm wonder if I can use `Executor.submit` rather than `Executor.map` to avoid the dead lock.

Comment: No, `submit` won't fix this. But I think you can only use `executor` at the top directory so all the tasks are independent. It isn't a perfect solution but is the easiest one and I think it is also good enough for most situations.